# How to implement auto scroll

Tags: javascript

How to implement auto scroll to next section of webpage on each scroll event but without excluding scroll bar with vanilla JavaScript.

I try with jQuery animate function, with scroll to function and fullpage.js library but no luck

Comment: Can you explain a bit further what you mean by autoscroll? Do you have any examples of other websites where they have what you are looking for and trying to replicate?

Comment: On page load scrollTop = 0, in normal circumstances when user issue scroll event page will be scrolled for some amount e.g. 50, so scrollTop will increment after each scroll. I want that when user issue first scroll page scrolls so that designated section be visible at the center of the screen. And not just to jump to it but to go smooth. Like when you click on navlik of onepage site with scroll-behaviour: smooth.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`scroll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scroll) or [`scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) methods to get what you are looking for. The former scrolls based on a pixel offset from the top of the page, whereas the latter scrolls to a given element.

---

From the MDN:

> The `Window.scroll()` method scrolls the window to a particular place in the document.

> The [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) interface's `scrollIntoView()` method scrolls the element's parent container such that the element on which `scrollIntoView()` is called is visible to the user.

---

For a smooth scrolling, you can in both approaches use the `smooth` behavior, like this:

```
// Smoothly scrolls to 200 pixels from the top
window.scroll({top: 200, behavior: 'smooth'});
```

and

```
var el = document.getElementById('fooBar');
// Smoothly scrolls to the top of the element provided
el.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});
```

Of course, if you want to do this based on a mousewheel event, you need to setup a listener for that (probably the `wheel` or `scroll` event).

Comment: Yeah, I know those. And I created js array with ids of elements that I want to scroll to (as ["id0", "id1", "id2", "id3", "id4" ]) and var currentSection = 0. If user scroll down I increment currentSection, and if user scrolls up i decrement it, and scroll to element of array that currentSection points to. But problem is that I don't know how to properly interact with that variable because if user scroll steady and slowly it works fine, but on more "aggressive" scroll it goes wild and jump from section 0 ti section 4 etc because variable increments multiple time before first one is resolved.

Comment: @JelenaLukic you might want to restrict the number of such inputs a user can make. For example max once every second or something. You can do this if you throttle your requests. Take a look at "throttling" in Javascript. "Debounce" could perhaps also work, but I think throttling is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I have the same issue on my project. And I tried to do it with _.throttle or _.debounce functions and I encounter same functionality that is described. I think that if we figure out how to completely prevent scrolling out of throttle functions it will work. But I don't know how to do it. Here is my version of

code:

```
let screens = ["#id1", "#id2", "#id3", "#id4", 
    "#id5", "#id6", "#id7"];
    let numberOfScreen = 0;
    let isScrolling = false;
    let lastScrollTop = 0;

    document.body.addEventListener("scroll",  _.throttle(()=>{
        var st = window.pageYOffset || document.body.scrollTop; // Credits: "https://github.com/qeremy/so/blob/master/so.dom.js#L426"
        let i = numberOfScreen;
        if (st > lastScrollTop){
            i++;
            if(i >= screens.length){
                i = screens.length-1;
            }
        } else {
            i--;
            if(i<0){
                i = 0;
            }
        }
        window.location = screens[i];
        setTimeout(()=>{
            numberOfScreen = i;
        },1000)
        lastScrollTop = st <= 0 ? 0 : st; // For Mobile or negative scrolling
    }, 1000, { 'trailing': false}));
```

`